# i want fetch last access date of tfs user using rest api

Tags: tfs

I have seen there is rest api for getting the data but that api using api version "4.1-preview.1" as its is supporting tfs 2018, **however my tfs version is this 
"Version 16.122.27102.1"** so that api version is not supporting me.so i could not able to fetch the "UserEntitlements details" using api.

api : https://abc.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview.1

How would I manage to get the similiar data as tfs 2018 ??

Comment: 16 **is** TFS 2018. Can you please update your question to provide more detail on the exact problem you're having when calling the REST API?

Comment: upgrade 2 is required for my tfs @DanielMann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Entitlements API is for VSTS only, it is not applicable to TFS.